# Hyperledger fabric setup multiple org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, setup-project

I want to setup a fabric network with multiple organisations in the financial industry.
Is there any detailed guide that helps me to decide what kind of implementation makes sense? Aka how many orderer nodes, how many channels, when private data, who has which rights, etc...
Kind of searching for a decision tree/flow chart, whatever...
If you can recommend anything I'd be really thankful
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Number of channels, use of private data, access control etc. depends on the use case. I would recommend going through the official fabric [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/developing_applications.html). Also if you want a highly available kubernetes n/w setup, there is already one sample available at [fabric-smaples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network-k8s)